# multi-line text box with popup menu

Tags: python, scripting, interface, add-on

How can I make a multi-line text box using the popup_menu function in my add-on?

The idea is that I could use it as a function that I could call anywhere and put any text in it.

Answer (score 4):

I just found this way of doing it.
Put this at the top of your add-on (you can also test it alone in the text editor):

```
import bpy

def ShowMessageBox(title = "Message Box", icon = 'INFO', lines=""):
    myLines=lines
    def draw(self, context):
        for n in myLines:
            self.layout.label(text=n)
    bpy.context.window_manager.popup_menu(draw, title = title, icon = icon)
```

You can then put the following anywhere in your code:

```
myLines=("line 1","line 2","line 3")
ShowMessageBox(lines=myLines)
```

Reminder: you can use a custom title and icon each time you call this function:

```
ShowMessageBox(title="Uh-oh.", icon='ERROR', lines=myLines)
```